# How to prevent class field(list) change in Python?

Tags: python

For example, I have a class with a field `__x`, which is a list:

```
class C():
    def __init__(self, xx):
        self.__x = xx
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x
    @x.setter
    def x(self, xx):
        raise Exception("Attempt to change an immutable field")
```

I can prevent changes such as these:

```
c = C([1,2,3])
c.x = [3,2,1]
```

But how can I prevent a change such as this?

```
c.x.append(4)
```

Comment: You can't, really. Trying to make things immutable is pretty tough in Python, unless you want to write a C-extension. Here, `list` objects are always mutable, you could define an "immutable" wrapper perhaps. Note, you can simply just not define a setter and it will throw an error

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Is it OK to use tuples inside my class then? I will justuse list(self.__x) every time I want it to be list. Or it's a bad practice?

Comment: How about converting the list to a tuple?

Comment: You can, of course, just return a copy of your list as well, and then `.append` simply won't matter

Comment: I think you are worrying to much about something you can't really solve. I can "mutate' your "immutable" class quite easy. `c = C(); c._C__x = [0, 1, 2]` remember, Python doesn't have private/public. In the end, you are relying on convention

Comment: @ttt whether or not tuples are suitable substitutes for lists is for you to decide. Why are you using a list right now?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Because I change it. I can append and remove someone from this list, but when I do it, I must do the same changes in my database. So I want to make my own "setter-like" method

Comment: @ttt well then use a list and return a copy of it, or a tuple if you'd prefer, but a copy would work `self._x.copy()`

Comment: @ttt 
**Because I change it. I can append and remove someone from this list, but when I do it, I must do the same changes in my database. So I want to make my own "setter-like" method**

If those are your needs you might want to have a look into `collections.abc.MutableSequence` and implement your custom list-like class.

Comment: @Massimiliano Sounds interesting! But I think returning a tuple will completely solve my problem. I will just define my own append_x() and remove_x() methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the final analysis, you cannot protect your objects from inspection and manipulation.
Also, always ask yourself "from whom, exactly?" when you want to "protect" data.

Sometimes it's just not worth the effort to code around users not reading the documentation.

That being said, you could consider `return tuple(self.__x)` in the getter.
On the other hand, if `__x` contains other mutable objects, that would not prevent a user from manipulating those inner objects. (`return list(self.__x)` would also return a shallow copy of the data, but with less implicit "hey, I'm supposed to be immutable!" signaling.)

Something you should definitely consider is to change `self.__x = xx` to `self.__x = list(xx)` in the `__init__` method, such that users doing

```
var = []
c = C(var)
```

can't "easily" (or by mistake, and again, there could be mutable inner objects) change the state of `c` by mutating `var`.

Comment: (There's also `copy.deepcopy`, but not worth the effort and expensive if called with every attribute access.)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga not for lists with mutable inner objects, such as lists of lists.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to accept an iterable on `__init__` and turn it to a tuple internally:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._tuple = tuple(iterable)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._tuple

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
      raise RuntimeError('can\'t reset the x attribute.')

c = C([1, 2, 3])
# c.x = 'a' Will raise 'RuntimeError: can't reset the x attribute.'
print(c.x)
```

A design like this one makes any object instantiated from the class immutable, so that mutating operations should **return new objects instead of changing the state of the current one**.

Let's say for instance that you want to implement a function that increment by one each item in `self.x`. With this approach you need to write something similar to:

```
def increment_by_one(c):
  return C(t+1 for t in c.x)
```

As there's a cost associated with creating and destroying objects the trade-offs between this approach (which prevents mutation of the `x` attribute) and the one suggested by @timgeb should be evaluated on your use-case.

Comment: Sure, but `C` could rely on `_tuple` being mutable internally.

Comment: @timgeb Not a request I inferred from the OP. A class like that (immutable) probably makes sense if a mutating operation returns a different instance.